# Add a new row by group based on a condition using datatable?

Tags: r, dataframe, datatable, row, data-manipulation

This is my current datatable:

```
ID  Stage Month 
200 A    2020-11   
200 B    2020-11  
200 C    2020-11   
201 A    2020-11   
201 B   2020-11  
...
```

I am trying to add a row to each ID/month group only if stages A B and C are present.

This would be my desired output:

```
ID  Stage Month 
200 A    2020-11   
200 B    2020-11  
200 C    2020-11 
200 All  2020-11  
201 A    2020-11   
201 B   2020-11 
...
```

I am new to datatable and R so any guidance would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can group by 'ID', 'Month', check `if` `all` the 'A', 'B', 'C' are found `%in%` the 'Stage', then concatenate 'Stage' with 'All' (`c(Stage, 'All)`) or `else` return the 'Stage'

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)[, .(Stage = if(all(c('A', 'B', 'C') %in% Stage)) c(Stage, 'All') 
              else Stage),  by = .(ID, Month)][, names(df1), with = FALSE]
```

-output

```
#    ID Stage   Month
#1: 200     A 2020-11
#2: 200     B 2020-11
#3: 200     C 2020-11
#4: 200   All 2020-11
#5: 201     A 2020-11
#6: 201     B 2020-11
```

---

Or using similar logic in `tidyverse`

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>% 
    group_by(ID, Month) %>% 
    summarise(Stage = if(all(c('A', 'B', 'C') %in% Stage)) c(Stage, 'All') 
           else Stage, .groups = 'drop') %>% 
    select(names(df1))
# A tibble: 6 x 3
#     ID Stage Month  
#  <int> <chr> <chr>  
#1   200 A     2020-11
#2   200 B     2020-11
#3   200 C     2020-11
#4   200 All   2020-11
#5   201 A     2020-11
#6   201 B     2020-11
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(ID = c(200L, 200L, 200L, 201L, 201L), Stage = c("A", 
"B", "C", "A", "B"), Month = c("2020-11", "2020-11", "2020-11", 
"2020-11", "2020-11")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-5L))
```